# jquery check if each loop was broken

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can break a jQuery.each loop by returning false from the callback function:

```
$('elements').each(function () {
  return false; // break
});
```

Is there a way to check that it was broken?

I want to break a nested loop, ideally without needing a variable to track it:

```
for (...) {
  $('elements').each(function () {
    return false; // break
  });
  // was the each loop broken? then break; again
}
```

Comment: No, it always returns the jquery collection it is called on.

Comment: `$().each` returns the source collection.  There's no property on the source collection to say "did the most recent action cancel itself".

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, there's probably a way without using .each, eg using `$(..).filter(..).length`

Comment: `// was the each loop broken? then break; again` - so your actual question is then, whether you can break out of these two nested loops in one go? You can, at least in vanilla JS, by using labeled blocks, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break#break_in_labeled_blocks (But I am guessing that probably won't work the same with jQuery's own loop implementations.)

Comment: @freedomn-m more "mentioned for completeness' sake" than actual recommendation :-)

Comment: Add a counter to your Loop and then compare it to the Length of items. You can also make a marker and change it when a break is going to happen. Lots of ways to do this.

Comment: `for` and than an `each` ? I think you're doing something really wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
var breakTest = false;
for (...) {
  $('elements').each(function () {
    if(...){
      ...
    } else {
      breakTest = true;
      return false; // break
    }
  });
  // was the each loop broken? then break; again
  if(breakTest){
    break;
  }
}
```

You can also do Code Blocks if you choose.